# It's All Just Noise To Me

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual, steganography

*(Note: This puzzle was originally made as part of a location-based puzzle hunt, so your final answer should be a place.)*

[image]

Hint 1:

> [image]

Comment: [Visual](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visual) and [steganography](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/steganography) tags?

Comment: Personally thinks it looks like a QR code

Comment: rot13: Znlor gur yrggref va gur 12 ol 15 yrggre tevq pbhyq or znccrq gb n fhotevqf bs gur nobir tevq.

Comment: rot13: Be znlor gur frg pbirevatf bs gur yrggref va gur yrggre tevq pna or znccrq gb n pbirevat bs pbeerfcbaqvat fhotevqf va gur nobir tevq.

Answer (score 1):

The first hint looks like a:

> word search:
>  [image]

I found the following words (but there might be more):

> Game of Thrones themed: BARATHEON, LANNISTER, MARTELL, STARK, TARGARYEN
>  Places: CHURCHROCK (city in NM), ERIE (lake and city in PA), GEORGIA
>  Puzzle themed: CODE, HUNT, MORSE, PUZZLE, TREASURE, WORDSEARCH
>  Miscellaneous: BEARD, HEAD, METASWITCH ([telecom company?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaswitch)), PHONES, PLAN, REAR, TEST, WALLPAPER